# не показывает бин

Tags: java, java-ee

Есть в java некий бин

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

    @ManagedBean(name = "testView", eager = true)
    //@ViewScoped
    @RequestScoped
    public class testView {

        @ManagedProperty(value = "#{s}")
        private String s = "тест";

        public String getS() {
            return s;
        }

        public void setS(String s) {
            this.s = s;
        }
    }
```

На xhtml пытаюсь вывести его значение.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<head>
    <title>Меню</title>
</head>

<body>
    #{testView.s}
</body>
</html>
```

И ничего не получается. Выводится белый лист. В дебаге я видел, что сперва в переменную s сетером кладется пустота (s=null) и соответственно потом берется пустота. Заменил в гетере

```
return s;
```

на

```
return "тест";
```

и заработало. что я делаю не так и как правильно?

Comment: а зачем нужно `@ManagedProperty` над строковым полем? если не ошибаюсь это нужно для инжекта другого бина, а для примитивных типов не нужно

Comment: @MrFylypenko можно и примитив заинжектить, но нужно только для инжекта.

Comment: Ваш код берет бин с именем s и кладет его в поле testView.s (потому что указана аннотация @ManagedProperty)

Comment: Да. понял. Исправил, все ок стало. Спасибо